# The receipt handle has expired while deleting message from SQS FIFO queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-sqs, aws-sqs-fifo

I tried to delete fifo queue message however my visibility timeout is 12 hours. But still i am unable to delete message after polling time. I have searched alot but didn't get any usfull way to delete the message. Can please someone help me in it.[Queue configuration screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxM8v.png), [Message Receiver screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyAjr.png), [Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1Vv0.png)

Comment: Could you please clarify what you have experienced? Did you try to delete the message _after_ the visibility period expired, or _before_ it expired? Can you show us your code?

Comment: First of all thanks for the quick response. I am using AWS console for this purpose and i am trying to delete the message after polling duration is completed. If i try to delete the message within polling duration. It works fine.

Comment: Image is already added to the Post

Answer (score 0):

When the **Amazon SQS console** is used to view the contents of an SQS queue, it is calling the same `ReceiveMessage()` API call as a normal app would call. This triggers message invisibility and increments the 'Receive Count' that is used to send messages to the Dead Letter Queue.

When `ReceiveMessage()` is called, **a different visibility timeout can be specified**. I suspect that the console is using a low visibility timeout so that it does not prevent queue consumers from being able to access the messages. Thus, when the polling is finished, the invisibility period has probably expired.

If this behaviour is not acceptable for your situation, you could **write your own 'message viewer'** that specifies a longer invisibility timeout.